# Can I use Google Identity Platform or Firebase Authentication as a SAML Identity Provider?

Tags: firebase-authentication, saml, google-identity

From the documentation, it is clear we can use SAML external Identity Providers with the Google Identity Platform.

But can we do the way around? To sign-in users to the external system with Google Identity Platform or Firebase via SAML protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, Google/Firebase is not an identity provider and does not offer this service/credentials, unless you are using GSuite.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en